# Typo in Job Description

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I found a typo in a [Job Description](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/112017/millions-of-chess-players-need-your-android-skills-chesscom?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=large-sidebar-blue-remote):

> high-performance code code.

Should be this reported? Should a high reputation user have the privileges to edit? Or should I just leave it and continue reading questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an advertisement by a company; they're paying StackOverflow to put it there, and *they alone* are responsible for the quality of their own texts.

That said, there is a big 'Ask a question' button on the bottom of the page. It has a specific option for general feedback on the job description. They will probably be grateful if you indicate the typo there.

[image]

Comment: For a more funny but fruity typo, check the first line of this ad: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/111339/product-manager-100k-crossover?searchTerm=crossover&offset=17